# GroupBy inside whereHas relation in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I'm building an application in `Laravel 5.5` where I'm pulling out data with `whereHas` relationship something like this:

```
$counts[] =  $company->interactions()->whereHas('contactsAssociation', function ($q) {
    $q->whereHas('company', function ($q) {
        $q->where('sub_type', 'like', 'Mutual Fund');
    });
})->count();
```

I want to group this by `contact_id` I mean I want to calculate the unique contact referred as `contactsAssociation` relationship in interaction model.

In my `Interaction` model following is the relationship:

```
public function contactsAssociation()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'contact_interaction',  'interaction_id', 'contact_id')->withPivot('company_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

and in `Contact` model I've:

```
public function company()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'company_contact','contact_id', 'company_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

also `sub_type` is table attribute. Help me out with this. Thanks.

Comment: Not enough information by unique contact means on which basis it is referred  as unique, *also sub_type is table attribute* what is the link of this attribute with your issue ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid unique contact means the data which I'm getting through the relational table `contact_interaction`, in simplest way I want to group `contact_interaction` table with `contact_id` but via `company->interactions()` relation Hope this clarifies the doubt

Comment: Ddi you try with $company->interactions()->distinct('id')->...?

Comment: @SimoneCabrino this will give unique interaction `id`? or will give unique `contact_id`

Comment: Sorry, use `contact_id`